# failed to acces a method of a class from the inside of another class

Tags: android

I have a mainAcitivity and two more class named"TestAdapter" and "CustomAdapter".
In my main activity i can normally call "TestAdapter" class from where i access database.
like this:

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
     TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(this);        

            onCreate() {

             mDbHelper.createDatabase(); 
            .....
```

My TestAdapter class looks like this.in this class there are different methods/functions:

```
public class TestAdapter 
 {

public  Context mContext;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
private DataBaseHelper mDbHelper;

public TestAdapter(Context context) 
{
    this.mContext = context;
    mDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(mContext);
}
```

there is a method inside this class like this:

```
public TestAdapter createDatabase()  {  mDbHelper.createDataBase();   }

public TestAdapter open() {  mDbHelper.openDataBase();}

 public void add_to_fav(String fav_word){}
```

i have created another class named CustomAdapter
But cant access add_to_fav  method inside this class to add data into database .

I need to call "add_to_fav" method of   TestAdapter class to update some data into the database.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
   TestAdapter t=new TestAdapter(this);
    t.add_to_fav("data")

}
```

But i cant access like this what should i need to do ??
Can anyone help about this?

Comment: What is the error you receive?

Comment: TestAdapter t=new TestAdapter(this); in this line said "constructor TestAdapter(CustomAdapter) is undefined"

Comment: There is your answer, CustomAdapter is not a Context so it cannot be used as the argument to the TestAdapter constructor.

Comment: You have defined your constructor using an argument of type `Context`.       In this line, `new TestAdapter(this)`, `this` refers to the current instance of `CustomAdapter`

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to create a new `TestAdapter` with argument `this`, which is a `CustomAdapter`.

You only have a constructor which takes a `Context` as argument.

```
public TestAdapter(Context context)
```

You'll have to provide an appropriate constructor:

```
public TestAdapter(CustomAdapter adapter) { }
TestAdapter test = new TestAdapter(this);
```

or

```
public TestAdapter() { }
TestAdapter test = new TestAdapter();
```

Comment: His TestAdapter class needs a Context. Your 2 proposed constructors will not help the OP.

Comment: Your context is unavailable since you're inside a class that doesn't inherit from it. I don't know enough Android to provide a solution for that, so unless you can get a `Context` object in the scope of your `CustomAdapter`, you'll have to revise the design.

Comment: Then you will need to pass the Context in the constructor of `CustomAdapter` and use that to initialise `TestAdapter`. However, you should state why you need a context.  Passing contexts around is often a sign of bad design.

Comment: @Simon He needs a Context for this: `mDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(mContext);`

Comment: So use the application context rather than passing an activity context around?  Perhaps most importantly, why a DatabaseHelper inside an adapter?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have a constructor for CustomAdapter that takes a Context.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    public  Context mContext;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context)
    {
        mContext = context;
    }
    TestAdapter t=new TestAdapter(mContext);
    t.add_to_fav("data")
}
```